# Triac Driver Datasheet - LED Trigger Current

Tags: driver, opto-isolator, triac

Looking at the datasheet for MOC30xx (here: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1806097.pdf) I see the following note on p4 under the table outlining the respective LED Trigger Currents of the various models (my emphasis):

> 3. All devices are guaranteed to trigger at an IF value ***less*** than or equal to max IFT. Therefore, recommended operating IF lies between max IFT (30 mA for MOC3020M, 15 mA for MOC3010M and MOC3021M, 10 mA for MOC3011M and MOC3022M, 5 mA for MOC3012M and MOC3023M) and absolute maximum IF (60 mA).

1. I can't get my head around why the IF has to be less than or equal
   than Max IFT. Is this a typo? "Should it be All devices are
   guaranteed to trigger at an IF value *greater* than or equal to max
   IFT"?
2. If so, does that imply the units with lower trigger currents are the
   more flexible and generic?
3. The prices for the components in this series are as similar, why
   not just produce the MOC3023 (which has the highest Off State
   Output Terminal Voltage and lowest LED Trigger current) and be done
   with it?

Comment: The point of view of specifications can be confusing. They are saying that the trigger threshold current of a given part will be *less* than the specification. So, if you use a  current *greater* than or equal to the specified current, it will be guaranteed to work.

Comment: #3 Some people want more sensitive parts, but they are more difficult to produce. They probably manufacture them the same and then *grade* the parts by testing them and sell them as different part numbers.

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense. And for #3 I'm assuming that although at 10pc or so the prices are similar, that in bulk there might be a significant financial difference in cost.

Comment: Further speculation ...  If the prices are similar now, maybe the more sensitive parts were more difficult to produce when the part was first released. Now, production methods have improved and it is easier to make the sensitive parts.